# Leading zero for hex string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read UART port with this:

```
print ("Attempt to Read")
readOut = serial_port.readline()
time.sleep(1)
in_hex = hex(int.from_bytes(readOut,byteorder='big')) 
print ("Reading: ", in_hex)
```

and then it gives me output e.g. like:

```
Attempt to Read
Reading:  0x6011401011403
```

So there is one leading zero missing before number 6. I can't find a way to add it without specifying in the code the length of the whole string (and I don't want to do that, becasue the string can have variable length e.g. like 0x056822). Could you please help?

Comment: What is readOut in this example? What makes you know a leading 0 is missing?

Comment: I read it from UART interface and in the above example readOut should have 7 bytes, so I would like to print it like: 0x06011401011403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inject a zero after 0x when the number of characters is odd:

```
if len(in_hex)%2: in_hex = in_hex.replace("0x","0x0")
```

Comment: Omg, simple and clever. I definitely should take a break today. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Even number of digits is guaranteed if you convert each byte to two characters:

```
hexstr = ''.join(format(b,'02x') for b in bytesequence)
```

Just prepend `"0x"` if you want.